# transformIgnorePatterns is not working properly for jest for react-native preset

Tags: react-native, jestjs, babel-jest

Got this error

```
    /node_modules/@react-native/polyfills/error-guard.js:14
    type ErrorHandler = (error: mixed, isFatal: boolean) => void;
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1350:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native/jest/setup.js:469:6)
```

However, I have already set

```
transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|react-(native|universal|navigation)-(.*)|@react-native-community/(.*)|@react-navigation/(.*)|bs-platform|(@[a-zA-Z]+/)?(bs|reason|rescript)-(.*)+)"
    ]
```

or

```
transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules"
    ]
```

I have set babel properly like

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);

  const presets = ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'];
  const plugins = ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'];
  return {
    presets,
    plugins,
  };
};
```

and I have already tried clearing the cache.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: `@react-native` is not a part of the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Add `@react-native` to your Jest configuration. Such as:

```
transformIgnorePatterns : [
      "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?@react-native|react-(native|universal|navigation)-(.*)|@react-native-community/(.*)|@react-navigation/(.*)|bs-platform|(@[a-zA-Z]+/)?(bs|reason|rescript)-(.*)+)"
    ]
```